# Scanner Class Error

Tags: java

I am using `Scanner` class to read data from a file. The file content is displayed properly but at the end it is throwing  `java.util.NoSuchElementException` error.What am I doing wrong here?

### Following is the code.

```
Scanner sc_file=new Scanner(new File("/host/sha.txt")).useDelimiter("\n");
while (sc_file.hasNextLine())
{
    System.out.println(sc_file.next());

}


sc_file.close();
```

---

Error Stack

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:855)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1364)
    at basicjava.Input_output.main(Input_output.java:34)
```

Comment: most probably the file /host/sha.txt is non existent..

Comment: maybe there's an extra empty line at the end of the text file or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\r\n` as the delimiter:

```
.useDelimiter("\r\n");
```

**Update:**

[hasNextLine()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29)

> Returns true if there is another line in the input of this scanner.

[next()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29)

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

So, basically what's happening is that for the last line `hasNextLine()` is returning true but somehow the last line does not seem to end with `\n` so it's not a complete token, which why `next()` is throwing `NoSuchElementException`.

You seem to be trying read the file line by line (as you are using `\n` as the delimiter for the `next()` method and `hasNextLine()` in your condition). So, I would recommend trying getting rid of the delimiter and using [nextLine()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) instead of `next()`:

```
scanner.nextLine();
```

Which would basically return the line disregarding whatever the line actually ends with.

Comment: Hi, I removed the delimiter and added a newline still I had the problem. The issue was resolved after giving nextLine() in out statement System.out.println(sc_file.nextLine()); I am wondering how do the next() should throw an error where as nexLine doesn't

Comment: +1 for coming back then catching the `next()` vs. `nextLine()`, I just wasn't seeing it.

Comment: @techrawther - you need to use the matching methods - `hasNext()` with `next()`  or  `hasNextLine()` with `nextLine()` - they compliment each other in terms of how they tokenize a line.

Comment: @BrianRoach: Thank you. Appreciate your encouraging comments.

Answer (score 0):

I tested that myself. I also get the NoSuchElementException if the last line is empty. So the solution is not to have the empty line at the end. Note that setting **.useDelimiter("\r\n")** still caused the error.